# cannot run code (error: no such file or directory) but can compile file C++ VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

**File structure** in folder `/home/cyan/proj10`

```
fst
 | -- include
 |     |-- fstlib
 |            |-- fst_reader.h
 |
 | -- lib
       |-- libfst.so

include
 | -- A.h
 | -- B.h

src
 | -- A.cc
 | -- B.cc

main.cc

CMakeLists.txt
```

`fst` folder is a library I added.

**CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(READ_FST VERSION 0.1.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fst/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fst/lib)
add_executable(READ_FST main.cc src/A.cc src/B.cc)
target_link_libraries(READ_FST ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fst/lib/libfst.so)
```

**A.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <B.h>
namespace me {
class A{
public:
    void init();
public:
    double func(double a, double b, double c);
private:
    B b_;
};
}
```

**A.cc**

```
#include <A.h>
namespace me {
void A::init() {
    b_.init(1.0, 2.0, 1.0);
}
double A::func(double a, double b, double c) {
    return b_.func(a, b, c);
}
}
```

**main.cc**

```
#include <A.h>
#include <B.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <./fstlib/fst_reader.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "defines": [],
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
            "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"],
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "cmake",
            "command": "cmake",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-Wall",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}/include",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}/fst/include",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build"
            },
            "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
            },
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

---

**Problem**

I can compile active file and intellisense is fine. But every time I click the `Run Code` button, it gives the following error:

```
cyan@machine:~/proj10$ cd "/home/cyan/proj10/" && g++ main.cc -o main && "/home/cyan/proj10/"main
main.cc:1:10: fatal error: A.h: No such file or directory
 #include <A.h>
          ^~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't match itself. Please make sure you show us a proper [mre].

Comment: Why are you compiling with gcc if you have a cmake file? Can't you just run cmake or even better install the cmake plugin and let that build for you

Comment: @AlanBirtles sorry I'm very new to this. I revised "label" and "command" in `tasks.json`  into "cmake". The same issue still exists.

Comment: If you're using the cmake plugin you don't need tasks.json at all

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thx I revised my question

Comment: @AlanBirtles sorry I don't quite get it. I am using CMake tool but still I couldn't run the file. Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Try following the tutorial in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/CMake-linux)

Comment: @AlanBirtles thx I've found where the problem is. You are right I didn't build CMake proj before. It is just I am still curious that how to run the code without using CMake but to use gcc

Comment: There's a tutorial for that in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Okay

#### First

Try use [CMake extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools)

#### Second

`Run Code` does one simple thing - it compiles and runs the program from your current file.

```
cd "/home/cyan/proj10/" && g++ main.cc -o main && "/home/cyan/proj10/"main
```

Compilation at this point knows nothing about your CMake project, compilation flags, include paths, etc.

If you're trying to build your entire CMake project this way, it won't work.
You need to build exactly the CMake project, and run exactly the compiled application (the easiest way to do this is with the extension from the first paragraph).

Comment: What is going on with this formatting? The explanation also doesn't clear anything up.

Comment: thx I've found where the problem is. You are right I didn't build CMake proj before

Comment: It is just I am still confused that how to run the code without using CMake but to use gcc

Comment: @sweenish `Run Code` is only used to run the currently open source code file as a program. It does not start building the CMake project.

Comment: Repeating yourself doesn't magically clarify what I stated was unclear. And you don't need to explain to me, *I know how the pieces are supposed to fit together.* Your answer isn't clear enough to really help someone who doesn't.

Comment: `Run Code` only appears in the headline. The tasks.json that OP posted is broken, and the task is called 'cmake'. So explain what you're actually talking about. You would also need to explain what cmake actually is, as OP doesn't know. Then, you'd need to explain the process, have cmake generate the makefile (likely build system from what I can glean), then just run make. But if you don't want to write a full cmake tutorial, a comment that links to documentation would be better, which was already done.